# Imposible alinear texto al centro con PhpWord

Tags: php, phpword

Resulta que estoy tratando de generar un fichero Word con PhpWord  (sin usar templates) y resulta que no consigo que al aplicar estilo a un addText funcione la alineación de dicho texto al centro.

Lo único que se me ocurre ya es que pueda ser que el word que tengo es la versión 13 pero me resisto a pensar que una funcionalidad tan básica del word genere estos problemas por culpa de la version.

¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema? 
¿Podría alguien ayudarme con alguna solución? En teoria debería ser:

```
 ‘align’=>’center’
```

El resto de los estilos que aplico funcionan bien, pone el tipo de letra y su tamaño de forma correcta pero la alineación al centro del texto no va ni a tiros a pesar de haber probado mil formas distintas.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  para mostrar cuál es el código que no funciona. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El detalles que tienes puede estar relacionado a la versión PHPWord que usas, te recomiendo como minimo usar la version v0.15.0.

Es suficiente con definir en el mètodo [addParagraphStyle()](http://ivanlanin.github.io/PHPWord/api/source-class-PHPWord.html#157-166) el estilo indicando la alineaciòn de esta forma:

```
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('myStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
```

Ejemplo:

```
$text = "Hola Miguel";

$PHPWord->addFontStyle('myStyle', array('bold'=>false, 'italic'=>false, 'size'=>15));
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('myStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText($text, 'myStyle', 'p2Style');
```

Revisa la documentaciòn:

http://ivanlanin.github.io/PHPWord/api/class-PHPWord.html